# Under their appropriate definitions, can one "obtain" what they have "created?"

Tags: american-english, business-language, reason-why

Having a simple discussion with my coworker, I mentioned that I was celebrating my two year anniversary with my girlfriend.

She asked me "What are you going to get her?" to which I replied, "Nothing. I have $5 to my name."

Once again, she asked the same question, and I said "I'm going to make something."

She claimed that making is getting, and I explained to her that obtaining is not the same as creating. This sparked an all out debate (her point being that to create something is to obtain it) which has driven us to not work near each other any longer, and we have ceased all contact.

Jokes aside, can "obtaining" be creating?

Answer (score 1):

> She asked me "What are you going to get her?" to which I replied, "Nothing. I have $5 to my name....  I'm going to make something."
>
> She claimed that making is getting.

I think what your co-worker meant was, "If you are making her something for her birthday, that still counts as *getting* her something."

"Get" has several different meanings.  Your co-worker used it to mean "give on the occasion of a birthday".

I think you were interpreting "get" to mean "buy".

Comment: If you are going to _make_ someting you have to _get_ the raw materials and then do work to add value to them (hopefully). Since the work is done by you the added value comes from your skill, creativity and time. Apart from the materials, I don't see how making something is the same as getting something. I'm with  the OP

Comment: This is the correct answer. "Get" in this context means *acquire* or *procure*. *"Can I get you a drink"* covers both *buy* (in a bar) or *make* (at home).

Comment: Absolutely agree with Aparente001 in regards to my interpretation of "get." However, my argument (and between her and I, there will always be more arguments) was more in the interest of comprehending the processes of "getting" and "creating."

BoldBen, however, hit the nail on the head. I'm new to these forums, and appreciate the response! Thanks to all.

Answer (score -2):

Could be. The bible (King James Version) says that Adam begat Seth, and Seth begat Enos, and Enos begat Cainan, and so on. That's an awful lot of begetting, or procreation as we call it these days.

*Beget* comes from the Gothic *bigitan* "to get, obtain." *Procreate* comes from the Latin *procreare* "to beget, bring forth". So it seems that there is some connection between creating and getting (or obtaining).

[Online Etymology Dictionary: beget](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=beget)

[Online Etymology Dictionary: procreate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=procreate)

Comment: You've gotten two different characters in the story confused.

Comment: I don't think so (Genesis 5:3-9, KJV). Spellings do vary between translations.

Comment: Aparente was referring to the characters in the story being my coworker and my girlfriend.

Comment: Thanks to you as well, for your input. As a result of yours being the first response, my coworker claimed victory as of yesterday.

Comment: @NaelCabana Hopefully, you are on speaking terms again.